# What is the difference between the custom view and the view it inflates in constructor?

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

We can create a custom component as follows:

```
public class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {  
    public MyLinearLayout(Context context) {  
      super(context); 
      doInflate();   
    }  
    public MyLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {  
       super(context, attrs);  
       doInflate();    
    }  
    // other constructors  

   public void doInflate(){  
      inflate(getContext(), R.layout.my_linear_layout_definition_xml, this);
      this.setVisibility(GONE);  
   }     


   // some logic to show view  
   public void show(CustomObject o) {   
     if(o.someCondition()) return;  
     this.setVisibility(VISIBLE);  
   }    
}
```

If I control the visibility via the `this` in the code example which I think is the `ViewGroup` the view never shows up. I.e. the `this.setVisibility(VISIBLE);`  does not work.

But if in the layout file (my_linear_layout_definition_xml.xml) I have:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/my_linear_layout_parent_container"
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:visibility="gone"
>
// other children views here...
```

And in the code I do instead of the previous snippet:

```
public void show(CustomObject o) {   
         if(o.someCondition()) return;    
         findViewById(R.id.my_linear_layout_parent_container)
         .setVisibility(VISIBLE);    
       }
```

The visibility actually works. I.e. from gone becomes visible.

So my question is why does this work and what is the relation/difference between the `my_linear_layout_parent_container` I inflate in the constructor and the `this` in my class?

Answer (score 0):

You answer is apparently contradictory, the this.setVisibility(GONE) works (because you said the view does not show up), but this.setVisibility(VISIBLE) doesn't? Did you set the visibility also in the xml?

I tried it and it worked for me. There is no difference between this.setVisibility() and findViewById(...).setVisibility(), so your code should be working properly. Could you be more specific about when you are calling the method show(CustomObject o)? Are you sure the method is not returning in that

`if(o.someCondition) return`

Please, detail further your question, I will edit my post with an answer after you do it, cheers

Comment: No I had no visibility set in the xml. The code is exactly as posted. Why do you say that there is no difference between `this` and `findViewById`? Those refer to different elements right? As `this` is the `root` right?

Comment: Jim, in your case, `this` and `findViewById` refer to the same element, from what I understood from your code. You inflated a layout through `inflate(getContext(), R.layout.my_linear_layout_definition_xml, this);`. The root viewgroup in this is `my_linear_layout_parent_container`, right? I believe that the compiler understands that `this` in yout class refers to the view you inflated, that is, the `my_linear_layout_parent_container` linear layout. Also, from what I saw in your code, you are setting visibility to gone as soon as you inflate the layout; is that line working?

Comment: @Jim Did you have any success with it?